# Why does the try catch block not intercept my thrown error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, promise, try-catch

If have a form which sends data to a firebase realtime database. The function to write the data looks like this:

```js
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from 'firebase/database';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const writeData = async (table, data, id) => {
  const db = getDatabase();
  let item = id ? `${table}/${id}` : `${table}/${uuidv4()}`;
  set(ref(db, item), {
    ...data,
  })
    .then((r) => {
      return r;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    });
};

export { writeData };
```

In another file, i have a form which, on submit, sends the date to the `writeData` function.
The submit part looks like this:

```js
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const responseData1 = {
      name: data.name,
      date: Date.now(),
    };

    const responseData2 = {
      subject: data.subject,
      verified: false
    };

    try {
      await writeData(DATABASE_NAMES.table1, responseData1);
      await writeData(DATABASE_NAMES.table2, responseData2);
      
      // update UI after successful form submit
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('new error', e);
      setFormError(true);
    }
  };
```

My problem is, if one of the `writeData` call in the submit fails, the error will be thrown with an error message in the browser console (Uncaught (in promise) Error). But the catch block will not be executed.

I tried several other options.

- Instead of throwing an error in the firebase file, return different values.
- Also in the form submit, i tried to use `.then` and `.catch` for each `writeData`-call.

Comment: Add `return` before `set`

Comment: What's the point of `.then((r) => {
      return r;
    })`? Your `writeData` function does not return anything.